# Why i ran bin/magento cache:flush after need sudo chmod -R -v 777 generated var pub

Tags: cache, magento2.2.4, command

I am using 2.2.4 Magento when I ran the this command every time `bin/Magento cache:flush`after. I need  `sudo chmod -R -v 777 generated var pub`, if not it will error.

how can I Solve this problem, thank you very much!!

Comment: it must be the same user who runs your webstack!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code....

```
php bin/magento cache:flush && chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static generated/
```

but why we give permission as ***cache:flush*** reflate data into ***var/cache*** ***var/page_cache*** directory.

Comment: flush after is same problem @MR.R DNATH

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: the issue is when i ran php bin/magento cache:flush command after , need going to putty login and then ran chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static generated/ everytime. how can i ran the command but don't need everytime to run chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static generated/. thank you!!^^"" @MR.R DNATH

Comment: You have to run chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static/ genarated/ after run php bin/magento cache:flush.

But one thing you can do  php bin/magento cache:flush && chmod 777 -R var/ pub/static/ generated/  . In single cmd.